# Maximum of 8 Notifications for my app in notifications window in Android?

Tags: android, notifications, bundle, android-notifications

Maximum of 8 bundled notifications?

I'm writing an app that shows notifications in the status bar (and in the notifications window) at specific times, according to alarms the user sets up.

Whenever there's 3 or more notifications issued, the OS bundles them together. So far, so good.

But it seems there's a maximum limit of 8 notifications for my app in the notifications window at all times. If I issue a ninth notification, the 'oldest' notification disapears from the group and the ninth appears.

I've tested the app on 2 Motorola phones with (what seems to be) vanilla Android 6.0 and 7.0. The issue happens with the 7.0 one (when Bundled Notifications were introduced). This is the code that generates the notifications:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntentPopup)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.q_statusbar_icon)
            .setCustomContentView(contentView) //my notifications have a custom layout
            .setSound(notificationSoundUri)
            .setVibrate(vibrate_pattern);

    Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(id, notification);
```

Unfortunately, there will be times when more than 8 notifications should be 'active' in the notifcations window (bundled together). Is there a workaround to this? Am I missing something?